# iconv cannot convert from ASCII.. why?

Tags: bash, ascii

[I have this file.](http://tiborzsitva.szm.com/ascii/input.txt)

If I open it in Total Commander with `F3` and press `S` the proper content will be shown.

I tried to do the same thing in bash with `iconv`:

`iconv -f ASCII -t UTF8 input.txt`

but I got this:

`iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`

If I do from `CP850` or `CP852`:

`iconv -f CP850 -t UTF8 input.txt`

`iconv -f CP852 -t UTF8 input.txt`

I will have some unwanted characters in the output:

`Ì¦ŮŢŮ`

How to have the requested content also in Linux Terminal? What encoding is used in Total Commander when it shows `ASCII (DOS-charset)`? Or is it a bug in `iconv`?

Comment: It's not ASCII so you can't convert from ASCII to anything else

Comment: Are you sure that that file is ASCII? Note: ASCII has only 128 characters. Could you provide a copy in the question (e.g. copied from TC?)

Comment: isn't the file already UTF-8?

Comment: okay, so how do we call the charset from which the old NortonCommander's panels were constructed? like █▓▒▒ ▀▌▄▀ ? I'm sure that the file is not in UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not ASCII so you can't convert the file from ASCII to anything else. After some investigation, encoding `CP437` appears to give a "good" visual representation. For future reference here's how I determined this.

```
# Workspace
mkdir picture
cd picture

# Get the file
curl http://tiborzsitva.szm.com/ascii/input.txt >x
file x
x: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators

# Try and convert with every possible conversion
for e in $(iconv -l | awk '{print $1}')
do
    iconv -f "$e" -t utf8 <x >"x.$e" 2>"x.$e.error"
done

# Delete the failed conversion attempts (those with error reports)
for f in x.*
do
    [ -s "$f.error" ] && rm -f "$f"
    rm -f "$f.error"
done

# Link identical files together
for f in x.*
do
    c=$(cksum <"$f")
    cf="x.cksum.${c// /_}"
    [ -f "$cf" ] && ln -f "$cf" "$f" || ln -f "$f" "$cf"
done
rm -f x.cksum.*

# See what each one looks like
ls -l x.*
less x.*

# The first one (437) looks good so look for a nice encoding name
iconv -l | grep -w 437
437 CP437 IBM437 CSPC8CODEPAGE437
```

I would suggest that `CP437` would do nicely

Comment: this is exactly I was looking for... :) thx But the bad thing here is that I never heard about `CP437` :( CP852 was always "enough" for me

Comment: @user3719454 read `man iconv` and you'll find the option to list available character sets for conversion with `iconv -l`. After that it's pretty much down to visual inspection

Answer (score 3):

[ASCII is a 7-bit encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Bit_width), and your file starts with a bunch of bytes `0xdb`, an 8-bit value.

If it's (partly) graphical, it's probably [one of the 8-bit DOS codepages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page). I tried with CP850 and CP437, and the latter seems to give a sensible picture.

Makes sense, since [CP437 is the original IBM PC code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and [CP850 the Latin-1 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). The former has more drawing characters, like the combined single/double lines, and vertically halved boxes, both of which are replaced with some accented letters in CP850.

```
$ $ iconv -f cp437 -t utf8 < input.txt | head -10
█████████████████████████████████▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀██▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀████████████████████████████
██████████████████████▀▀▀▀ ▄▄▄▄  ▄█▓▓▓▓█▌  ▄█▓▓▓▓█▄▄ ▀█████████████████████████
███████████████▀▀ ▄▄▄▄▄▓█▓▓▓▒▒▐▌▐▓▓▒▒▒▒▓█▌▐█▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▀█  ▄▄▄▄ ▀██████████████████
██████▀▀▀▀▀▀ ▄▄▄▀█▓██▓█▓▒▒▒▒░░░█ █▒░░░░▒▌░▓█▄░░░░░░▄█ █▓▒▒▀█▄ ▀▀▀██████████████
██▀ ▄▄▄▓▒▄ █▓▓██▌▐▒█▓▒██░░░░░░▄█░▀█▄▄▄▄▀░ ░ ▀▀██▒▓▓█▌▐▌▒▒░░▓█▌▐█▄▄▄▄▄ ▀▀███████
██ ███████ █▒▒▓▀▄▐░▓▒░█▀▄▄▄▀▀▀▀                ▀▀▀▀▀ ▐▓▓▓▒░▓█ █▓▒░░░▒▒▓▄ ▀█████
██ ▓▓▓████▌▐░░▄▀▄ ▄▄▀▀                   ░░  ░░░░     ▀▀▀█▒█ ▐█▄░░░░░░▒▓█ ▄▄ ██
██ ▒▒▒▓████ ▓▄▀▀ ▀   ░   ░ ░░█▓▄▌  ▄░░ ░░██░░████░░  ░         ▀▀██▄▄▒▓█▌▐█▀ ██
██ ░░░▒▓█▀          ░▒░  ░░░▒▓▒▓█ ▐▓▒░░▒▒▓█░░▓▓█▓░░█▓█▓ ▐▓░        ▀▀▀█▓ ██░ ██
██ ▄▄▀▀    ▄▄▄█▓░  ░▒▓░ ░▒▓▒▓▒░▒▓ ▓▒▓▒░▓▓▒▓▒▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▓▒▓▒▌ ▀▄▄█▓███         ▀█
```

(Well, it doesn't seem to look that good here, on SE, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @roaima, nah, I should be saying that; you were faster.

Comment: @roaima, the creature lower down is waay more interesting than the stone arch at the top, but I don't want to copy more than that without permission. I think this far I can claim fair use for demonstration etc...

Comment: @ilkkachu thx a lot